# How to escape file path for burned-in text-based subtitles with FFmpeg?

Tags: windows, macos, ffmpeg, video, subtitles

I'm trying to burn text-based subtitles into a video using ffmpeg, via the command line option `-vf` followed by `subtitles=`(*filename*)`:si=`(*subtitle index*). I need this to work for both Windows and macOS.

On Windows, I've only been able to get this to work if *filename* is a file in the current working directory with no special characters like spaces or apostrophes. Unless *filename* is that simple, I get the error:

> "Unable to parse option value *mangled filename* as image size"

I've had better luck with macOS, but still can't get around *filename* containing an apostrophe. For example:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "Doesn't work.mkv" -vf "subtitles='Doesn'\''t work.mkv':si=0" -c:v vp9 -row-mt 1 -crf 24 -c:a:0 libvorbis foo.webm
```

...or...

```
ffmpeg -y -i "Doesn't work.mkv" -vf "subtitles='Doesn'\\\''t work.mkv':si=0" -c:v vp9 -row-mt 1 -crf 24 -c:a:0 libvorbis foo.webm
```

...both result in the error:

> Unable to open Doesnt work.mkv

I've tried to follow advice from these two Stack Overflow threads:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71597897/unable-to-parse-option-value-xxx-srt-as-image-size-in-ffmpeg
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916331/escape-special-characters-in-ffmpeg-subtitle-filename

...and general documentation on escaping for ffmpeg, but none of that helps. You can see in the second Stack Overflow thread above someone gave up, saying "The only solution I found was using a file without special characters local to your working directory".

That was back in 2017. The first thread is more recent (2022), but the advice given there simply isn't working for me.

Anyone know a better solution for this? I'm beginning to wonder if the only solution is the ridiculous extra step of extracting any text-based subtitles I need into a new, simply-named file in the current working directory.

(Image-based subtitles are much easier to handle, by the way.)

---

**Update**: Based on [the answer provided by @Rotem](https://superuser.com/a/1822055/167207) below, I wanted to show what the solution looks like on a closer to real-life Windows example (and, damn, is it ugly):

```
ffmpeg -y -i 'V:\Show Title\Season 1\Show Title - S01E01 - Somebody''s Something.mkv' -vf "subtitles='V\'\:\\\\Show Title\\\\Season 1\\\\Show Title- S01E01 - Somebody\\\'s Something.mkv':si=0" -c:v vp9 -row-mt 1 -crf 24 -ss 00:00:00 -t 480 -c:a libvorbis foo.webm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the subtitles file name is `Doesn't work.mkv`, we may use the following syntax:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "Doesn't work.mkv" -vf "subtitles='Doesn\'\'t work.mkv':si=0" -c:v vp9 -row-mt 1 -crf 24 -c:a:0 libvorbis foo.webm
```

---

According to [FFmpeg Utilities Documentation](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-utils.html.gz#quoting_005fand_005fescaping), it looks like `"subtitles='Doesn\''t work.mkv':si=0"` supposes to work.

Maybe the other `\` is required due to the Windows shell command-line (I don't really know).

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion actually fixed the macOS problem, rather than being a direct answer for Windows, but at least encouraged me to try harder with Windows. Windows needed `\\\'` for an apostrophe in a file name, and, for path starting with a drive, like `V:\ ` it needed... wait for it... `V\'\:\\\\ `, plus all other `\ ` in the path to be QUADRUPLED to `\\\\ `. I think it's confusion over an improperly escaped `:` that leads to the nonsensical "image size" error.

Comment: (By the way, I had to edit the above comment many times to get the Stack Exchange escaping to work right. Having a backslash before a closing backtick escaped that backtick. After numerous tries, the easiest solution was to add a space between the backslash and the closing backtick, rather than wasting more time on yet another escape sequence mystery.)

Comment: I tested my solution using FFmpeg 5.1.2-full_build-www.gyan.dev, before posting my answer, and it worked in Windows 10 command line. `-vf subtitles="Doesn\\\'t work.mkv":si=0` is also working. Doubling the quote `''` is required because it is placed inside a quoted string: `'string'`...